# Polynomial division proof. Spivak chapter 3, problem 7

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials

This is for Spivak's Calculus, third edition, chapter 3, problem 7. It says

> Prove that for any polynomial function f and any number a,there is polynomial g(x) such that f(x) = (x-a)g(x) + b. Proof is possible by induction on degree of polynomial

Proving for one degree is easy, so I'll skip it. My problem is while proving k+1. The solution that the book provides is

[problem solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzjAl.png)

I know it is in Spanish (my native language), but I hope it is basic or obvious enough to understand. Anyhow, my attempt is as follows:
$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...a_{k+1}x^{k+1} $

and I can get a k degree polynomial (which is less than the original k+1 degree) by subtracting the term $c_{k+1}x^{k+1} $,  so we have:

$f(x) - a_{k+1}x^{k+1} = (x−a)g(x)+b  $

so far it matches the answers I've found on the internet, but I don't know how to turn that into the answer:

$f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a) = (x−a)g(x)+b  $

So my question is how can I turn
$a_{k+1}x^{k+1} $  into $ a_{k+1}(x-a) $
or am I trying to solve this incorrectly from the beginning?

I am new at proofs and I am studying by myself, so the answer is probably simple, but I have been stuck on this for a while now and I can't figure it out. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typo. $f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)$ should have been $f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)^{\color{red}{k+1}}$, otherwise, I don't see how the degree of the polynomial would change for higher power.

Since $f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}$ is of degree at most $k$, we can write it as

$$f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}=(x-a)g(x)+b$$

$$f(x) =(x-a)[g(x)+a_{k+1}(x-a)^k]+b$$

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @ManuelMares the English version does not have that typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in effect, this is a typo. But there is another way to solve this typo that such provided by Siong Thye Goh. In the construction of  $h(x)$ we only can do this:
$h(x)=f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-a)$ must be $h(x)=f(x)-a_{k+1}\color{red}x^\color{red}{k}(x-a)$, notice the difference, we only add $x$ power $k$ but not power the all monomio. Still this equation work for the proof. What do we obtain in this form?

Now, since $h$ is a polinomial with dregree $\le k$, by assumption(complete induction), $h$ can be represented as:

$$h(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b$$

$$f(x)-a_{k+1}x^{k}(x-a)=(x-a)g(x)+b$$

So,

$$f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b+a_{k+1
}x^{k}(x-a)=(x-a)[g(x)+a_{k+1}x^{k}]+b$$

This complete the proof. Notice that the last form is more easy than obtained previusly (we only have $a_{k+1}x^{k}$ not $a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}$ ).

Please send me any error.